# Implementar telas em list fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em meu primeiro projeto com a `ListFragment` procurando na internet em tutoriais e até no curso online que estou fazendo.

Quando é criado o `onListItemClick` ele envia um `Toast` pra tela, mas eu quero que abra uma nova tela em vez de mostrar uma mensagem quando clica no item da *list*. Para constar, neste projeto estou utilizando [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Este é o código que fiz por enquanto:

```
ListView ListViewSegunda;
String[] linhas = {"305", "306", "315"};    
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, linhas);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}       
@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do something with the data
  }
```

Agradeço a ajuda da comunidade. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Se for parar iniciar uma nova `Activity`, basta uma simples `Intent`:

```java
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriAplicacao); // Ou algo do género
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Se for para substituir o `ListFragment` por um outro `Fragment` já é mais complicado. Eu costumo enviar o pedido para a `Activity` e lá fazer o seguinte:

```java
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentor, new OutroFragment()).commit();
```

Em que `OutroFragment` é o `Fragment` que se quer abrir, e `R.id.contentor` é o contentor no layout onde está o `ListFragment` e para onde vai o `OutroFragment`.

Espero que ajude. Diz algo se precisares de mais ajuda.